# What app registration preview permissions/scopes required to read user groups and group users from azure AD using Asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I’m getting unauthorized user when trying to read groups that I belong to with User.read permissions

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Above is the table lists the Graph API permission scopes and explains the access granted by each.

You can refer this table and assign the required permission scope.

Allows the app to read the basic profile of all groups in the organization on behalf of the signed-in user, you would be needing Group.ReadAll permission.

Hope it helps.